# How to add space between nav bar links?

Tags: html, nav

I'm trying to put space between nav bar links. Can anyone help me do this?

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>007 NIGHTFIRE DATA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><center><font color="#FFD700">007 NIGHTFIRE DATA</center></h1></span></font>
    <nav>
        <center>
        <a href="/HOME/">HOME</a>
        <a href="/GAMEPLAY/">GAMEPLAY</a>
        <a href="/IMAGES/">IMAGES</a>
        <a href="/VIDEOS & TRAILERS/">VIDEOS & TRAILERS</a>
        <a href="/GAME HELP/">GAME HELP</a>
        </center>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Note that the `<center>` tag was deprecated in HTML 4.01 in 1999 (twenty years ago), and as of HTML 5 in 2014 (five years ago) it is obsolete.  I suspect that, but don't understand why, most people that still use this tag are young enough that they should never have learned it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use Margin or Padding CSS properties.

1. https://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/

Answer (score 0):

By using margin ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.nav{
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right:5px;
}
</style>
<title>007 NIGHTFIRE DATA</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><center><font color="#FFD700">007 NIGHTFIRE DATA</center></h1></span></font>
<nav>
<center>
<div class="nav"><a href="/HOME/">HOME</a></div>
<div class="nav"><a href="/GAMEPLAY/">GAMEPLAY</a></div>
<div class="nav"><a href="/IMAGES/">IMAGES</a></div>
<div class="nav"><a href="/VIDEOS & TRAILERS/">VIDEOS & TRAILERS</a></div>
<div class="nav"><a href="/GAME HELP/">GAME HELP</a></div>
</center>
</nav>
```

Hope this might help you!

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to put the CSS coding into HTML of the answer you provided? Can't seem to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Updated , have a look! .